# how to use toDataURL with image onload function?

Tags: image, canvas, onload

```
function resetDisplayImg(){
var tempImage = new Image();

tempImage.src=document.getElementById("myCanvas").toDataURL("image/png");
tempImage.onload=function(){
context.drawImage(tempImage1,0,0,Canvas_WIDTH,Canvas_HEIGHT);
}
```

}

Everytime when i call the function above, i have to call two times then it will function correctly. I know with function "onload" can solve this problem but the problem still occur even if i applied it. Is there any mistake that i had made?

Answer (score 0):

put the `.src` line after the `onload`

**BUT** you shouldnt be doing this in the first place. You are allowed to directly draw one canvas to another, so instead you can just write:

`context.drawImage(document.getElementById("myCanvas"), 0, 0);` and be done!